# Deploy REST API over multiple servers world-wide, but stay in sync

Tags: api, rest, networking, deployment, latency

I've built a REST API with a pretty decent latency. Each request is answered in ~100 ms with a thousand requests per second. This is however with a relatively low physical distance to the data center. The users of this API would, however, be spread all over the globe. From the US for example (to a data center in Germany), the response time for a single request is ~400 ms under no load.

What would be the best approach to deploying this API? I suspect multiple servers at different locations, with a load balancer in front. How would I ensure that the MySQL database would stay in sync between the servers in that case?

With multiple servers and a load balancer, the costs rise exponentially, which is something I can hopefully afford in the future, but not at the moment.

I'd love to hear your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik. for big projects people use event sourcing with an event storage and microservices and message queues between them or a basic solution is polling the event storage through a simple REST API something like send me the latest events since the last event I received. If you can accept eventual consistency, then I think this approach can work pretty well. It makes writing somewhat slower, but reading can be very fast with it. No need to sync the MySQL databases directly, you just pull the latest events and use a projection to update the local MySQL database. So the event storage is the single source of truth.

Comment: Sounds interesting, how would that work exactly? Because you still need to pull the latest events from a single server, wouldn't that add the same latency?

Comment: @Kiekem It adds latency only to the writes. Because first you store the events in the event storage, then sync the query databases with the event storage. But meanwhile your users can read the query databases with low latency and those query databases can be anywhere around the globe. For most scenarios write latency does not matter as much as read latency. Even for chat messages can have a few secs delay. At least that's what I got from Facebook nowadays.